# Login user right after registration - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to login a user right after registration with the code below.
I am not seeing anything wrong in my code by I get the following error

> Method [guard] does not exist.

I have as well imported use

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
```

**RegisterUser**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // $this->create($request->all());
    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    UserVerification::generate($user);
    UserVerification::send($user, 'My Custom E-mail Subject');

    $this->guard()->login($user)->with('status', 'Registration successfully done.');

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());

}
```

Comment: Show full code of your controller, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method named `guard` in your controller. Use the `login` method in  `Auth`.
Use `Auth::login($user);` to manually log in a user

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    // $this->create($request->all());
    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    UserVerification::generate($user);
    UserVerification::send($user, 'My Custom E-mail Subject');

    \Auth::login($user);

    return $this->registered($request, $user)
        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());

}
```

If you want to use a custom guard you can specify the guard `Auth::guard('guard-name')->login($user)`

Answer (score 0):

After Registration if your custom guard is not working, in your Custom Registration controller put this below function, it will work for you. after registration your custom guard will work 100%.

```
protected function guard(){return Auth::guard('dealer');}
```

Comment: please edit your answer and use StackOverflow's editor features for more readability.